# error al intentar mostrar valores de un vector en angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Tengo un vector de un tipo de dato (clase) definida por mi. El error que tengo es que al intentar imprimir desde la posicion 1 en adelante me muestra esto: "_this.inmuebles[1] is undefined" , si intento imprimir solo la posicion 0 si me lo muestra bien. Imprimi la longitud del vector inmuebles y al parecer si se esta insertando la variable "inmueble" porque muestra la longitud correcta, pero no se que pasa. Dejo el código a continuacion:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HostlistService } from '../servicios/hostlist.service';
import {$,jQuery} from 'jquery';
import { Inmueble } from '../modelos/inmueble';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-slider',
  templateUrl: './slider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slider.component.css']
})
export class SliderComponent implements OnInit {
  inmuebles: Inmueble[] = [];
  i = 1;
  url: string = "d782a4ae-733f-b7c4-ed11-5ba553455e04_fot01_c";

  constructor(private hostlistService: HostlistService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.cargarJson();


  }

  anteriorInmueble(){
    this.i=this.i-1;
  }

  siguienteInmueble(){
    this.i=this.i+1;
  }

// metodo para cargar el Json recibido de la petición
  cargarJson(){
    var foto1,foto2: string;
    foto1 = "fot0", foto2 = "fot";
    var pos: number;
    this.hostlistService.getInmuebles().subscribe(
        result => {
            if(result.success === true){
                for(const item of result.data) {
                    pos = 0;
                    const inmueble = new Inmueble();
                    inmueble.nombre = item.nomb_prod_c;
                    inmueble.id = item.id;
                    inmueble.estacionamiento = item.estan_c;
                    inmueble.baño = item.banof_c;
                    console.log(inmueble.nombre);
                    (item.fot01_c != "") ? inmueble.fotos[0]="true": inmueble.fotos[0]="false"; pos++;
 
                    this.inmuebles.push(inmueble);
               
                    console.log("----->"+this.inmuebles[0].fotos[0]);
                    console.log("----->"+this.inmuebles[1].fotos[0]);

            }
        }

        },
        error => {
            console.log(error);
        }



    );
  }

}
```

esta es la clase Inmueble:

```js
export class Inmueble {
  nombre: string;
  id: string;
  baño: number;
  estacionamiento: number;
  metro: number;
  precio: number;
  fotos: boolean[];
}
```

Espero puedan ayduarme, tengo horas intentando resolver y no doy con el error.

Comment: Julian  como va?, te recomiendo mejorar la pregunta en cuanto a ortografía (mayúsculas después de punto por ejemplo), signos de puntuación (esto mejorará la comprensión de tu inquietud) y en dejar más limpio el código a presentar (quitar todo el código comentado).

Comment: ya mejore mi pregunta.

Comment: me di de cuenta de que si creo un segundo objeto "inmueble2" y hago:                     console.log("----->"+this.inmuebles[0].nombre); y console.log("----->"+this.inmuebles[1].nombre); si me muetsra los datos, así que veo que el problema esta relacionado con la clase, que podra ser?

Comment: Te da error en el console.log? Es que si es así es normal que te de error, ya que cuando inicias el for tienes 0 elementos, cuando añades tienes 1 elemento y en ese log estas pidiendo el segundo elemento que aún no tienes. Tendrías que mostrar esos logs fuera del bucle

Comment: Supongo que usas la variable pos a modo de contador de iteración. En cada iteración añades un elemento, y en cada una de las iteraciones estás haciendo console log del elemento que está en la posición [1] (es decir, el segundo elemento). Si sólo has añadido un elemento, es normal que diga que es undefined. O añades el console log fuera de la iteración o utilizas pos como índice (pero antes de hacer pos++).

Answer (score 0):

Fíjate en tu bucle `for`:

```
for (const item of result.data) {
    pos = 0;
    const inmueble = new Inmueble();
    inmueble.nombre = item.nomb_prod_c;
    inmueble.id = item.id;
    inmueble.estacionamiento = item.estan_c;
    inmueble.baño = item.banof_c;
    console.log(inmueble.nombre);
    (item.fot01_c != "") ? inmueble.fotos[0]="true": inmueble.fotos[0]="false";
    pos++;

    this.inmuebles.push(inmueble);

    console.log("----->" + this.inmuebles[0].fotos[0]);
    console.log("----->" + this.inmuebles[1].fotos[0]);
}
```

En cada iteración estás añadiendo un solo objeto `Inmueble`, ¿verdad? Entonces en la primera iteración, esta línea te dará error: `console.log("----->"+this.inmuebles[1].fotos[0]);` porque todavía no tienes dos objetos en la lista, o sea, `this.inmuebles[1]`, no existe aún.